# How can I show a button when all views are viewed in viewpager?

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

Right now I have a save button that I want to show only if all the views inside a viewpager are shown. That means that when the user swipes between views and have seen all views inside a viewpager, then show a save button.

I want to show the save button on every view when they have seen all views hereby after.

The trouble I am having is how to set up the logic. I started out with setting the save button invisible until the last view of the viewpager. On the last view of the viewpager, show the save button. But the problem is when the user goes to the last view (there's a save button) and then goes back to a previous view, the save button is gone.

So, I was wondering how can I show the save button permanently on all views after the user has seen all views?

Here's what I have so far:

I have this snippet inside my InstantiateItem() :

```
if(isViewed)
{
 save_button.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);
 System.out.println("Is this called? isViewed = true");


 }else if (position == numberOfPages.size()-1) {

 isViewed = true;
 save_button.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);
 }
```

where

```
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
isViewed = true;
}
```

EDIT:

I tried the following solutions but with no luck.

```
Button save_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
                    if(isViewed[position])
                    {
                        save_button.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    if (position == numberOfPages.length-1 && !isViewed[position]) {
                        isViewed[position] = true;
                        save_button.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    isViewed[position] =true;
```

And

```
isViewed[position] = true;
                    if (isViewed[position] == isViewed[numberOfPages.length-1]) {
                        save_button.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);
                    }
                        if (isViewed[position]) {
                            save_button.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);
                        } else {
                            save_button.setVisibility(Button.INVISIBLE);
                        }
```

Comment: Why you are using `isViewed` single variable? It will set value once and always give the same. You can create an array of boolean having same size as the `noOfPages.size()` and set the value in boolean array corresponding to the position of the page that has been visited.

Comment: are you using fragment with viewpager?

Comment: No fragment. Only views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `onPageSelected`, do the following

```
if(isViewed)
{
 save_button.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);
 }
 if (position == numberOfPages.size()-1) {
 isViewed = true;
 save_button.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);
 }
```

Note the above are two seperate if statements.

Make your `isViewed` global and default to `false`.

Comment: Thanks for answering, StoneBird. I tried your solution but with @Pr39y's answer of making the isViewed an array equal to numberOfPages.size() and it only makes the last save button show and not all previous ones after the last one is shown.

Comment: I've edited my post to show what I have attempted. Thanks a lot again! :D

Comment: @KalaJ no, don't use array in this case. This is because you want `isViewed` to be shared across all pages, so that once it's flipped to `true`, it will be `true` for all of your pages.

Comment: Okay but here's my problem with your current approach. Right now if the view is open/seen, it automatically adds the save button. I want it so that the user has to see ALL views first before showing the save button permanently. Right now, it shows the save button immediately when the view starts.

Comment: @KalaJ that's why I say you should initialize `isViewed` to `false`, and only change it to `true` in the last page.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ijFxQR7w. I stripped out code to reveal only the necessary details. Let me know if you have any questions about anything. Thank you so much

Comment: @KalaJ did you initialize visibility in your xml? Anyway see the edit

Comment: Well right now, I have two pages in my viewpager. Both pages have the save button immediately. I didn't have to access the last page first before seeing the save button.

Comment: btw, no I didn't initialize visibility in xml

Comment: @KalaJ you should set your button visibility in xml to `gone` so that your button is initialized as hidden.

Comment: If I set the button visibility to invisible, the button is initialized as hidden but it doesn't come back on the screen after I go to my last page and back to the first page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64952/discussion-between-kala-j-and-stonebird).

Answer (score 1):

`boolean []isViewed = new boolean[noOfPages.size()];`

```
 @Override
 public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        if(isViewed[position])
            {
               save_button.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE); 
            }
        else  {
               save_button.setVisibility(Button.GONE); 
            }
      isViewed[position] = true;
 }
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working. I will debug. Looks like isViewed is not being hit.

Comment: which statement is not being hit?

Comment: Actually it just seems to be returning false. The save button is still invisible. It's not showing up at all.

Comment: is it calling `onPageSelected`?

Comment: yes it is. For some reason, the save button is still invisible though? :(

Comment: It seems like this is never returning true: if(isViewed[position])
                        {
                            save_button.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);
                            
                        } Does it matter if I used length instead of size() for this part: boolean []isViewed = new boolean[noOfPages.size()];?

Comment: Okay, it semi-works. I just need to switch around the positions? It seems like the save button is shown on first view when I just want to show it after the user has seen all views. So it should appear on the last position first and then for all previous views. Right now, it's appearing on the first view, invisible on the second and then when I go back to first and then back to second, the button is shown. It works but in the wrong direction?

Comment: I think it's something to do with my global variable of save_button. Where should I set this the save button findview by id? and boolean []isViewed = new boolean[noOfPages.size()];?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64646/discussion-between-pr38y-and-kala-j).

Comment: If I need my save button inside my pageradapter class and my collection activity, don't I need to make save button global? How can I prevent this?